# Manipulate object and array returned by Promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, object, promise

[image]

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   var size = req.params.size ? parseInt(req.params.size) : 20;
   var page = req.params.page ? req.params.page>0 ? (size&(parseInt(req.params.page)-1)) : 0 : 0;

   db.knex.select('t.id', 't.title', 't.slug', 't.start_date', 't.end_date', 't.enable_date', 't.disable_date', 't.featured', 't.category', 't.status')
   .from('tournament AS t')
   .limit(size).offset(page)
   .then(result => {
          let arr = [];
          arr = result.map(x => {
               db.knex.select('td.id', 'td.d_title')
               .from('tournament_detail as td')
               .where('td.tournament_id', x.id)
               .asCallback((err, row) => {
                    if(err) return console.error(err);
                    x['detail'] = row;
                    console.log(x);
                    return x;
                });
          })
     }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
         res.send(err)
     })
 });
```

this code produces this result shown in the images but i want those objects to be merged into an array.

how do i achieve it?

help please.

and my expected output is something like this
[image]

Comment: The objects are already merged into an array, i.e. the `result` array from your first call.

Comment: that is true but i wanted to add an key value by making secondary sql call and push that return value to the first call.

Comment: Please post what your expected output would look like

Comment: I've updated my post check the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that you're using `result.map` which will not wait for promises to resolve, and then you're using a knex query which is promise based. Instead, you'll need to use a mapping function that waits for promises to execute. If you are on node 8 or above, you should be able to use the native `Promise.all`, if you are on a lower version I'd recommend trying out the [Bluebird library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bluebird). That will change your code to something like below.

```
var Bluebird = require('bluebird');

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
   var size = req.params.size ? parseInt(req.params.size) : 20;
   var page = req.params.page ? req.params.page>0 ? (size&(parseInt(req.params.page)-1)) : 0 : 0;

   db.knex.select('t.id', 't.title', 't.slug', 't.start_date', 't.end_date', 't.enable_date', 't.disable_date', 't.featured', 't.category', 't.status')
   .from('tournament AS t')
   .limit(size).offset(page)
   .then(result => {
          return Bluebird.map(result, x => {
               return db.knex.select('td.id', 'td.d_title')
               .from('tournament_detail as td')
               .where('td.tournament_id', x.id);
          });
     }).then((arr) => {
         console.log(arr);
     })
     .catch(err => {
         console.log(err);
         res.send(err)
     })
 });
```

In the above, we are using Bluebird.map to loop through the results executing the knex promises on them to retrieve the second data set. In the final then, the `arr` value will be a collection of the results of the map queries.

Using the native `Promise.all` is similar, simply replace the `Bluebird.map` with `Promise.all` and you should be good to go.

As an aside, you can also make this code even nicer using async/await if you're on nodejs 8 or higher. With that, you can keep your `results.map` and use an async function as well.

Forwarning, I've not run this code so it may have some syntax errors and such. But using Bluebird.map is what you want to do for this.

Comment: Why not just use `Promise.all()` instead of adding an extra library?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I assumed by the use of "var" this was an older version of node, however I realise now there are arrow functions so Promise.all would be fine. As an aside, async would make this even nicer and is usable within a map or forEach.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen I've updated my answer with some details of Promise.all and a hint towards async/await.